# Datetime manipulation with lists

Tags: python, list, datetime

This is hard to explain but I will try to represent this in a small example:

```
NDD = 11/1/2018
```

number of payments:

```
1 0 2 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 1
```

Since the first month starts with `11` in NDD then the first element of my list will be `11`, to compute the next element I take the first month (`11`) and subtract the first payment `1` and then the second element is `10`. This proceeds and the pattern is clear if you follow the logic so I will have

```
11 10 10 8 8 6 5 4 4 2 1 12
```

To make it even more clear:

```
number_of_payments = [1 0 2 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 1]
```

Algorithm:

Step 1 - Create an empty list:

```
dates = []
```

Step 2 - Append the first month of NDD to the first index of dates

```
dates.append(NDD.month)
```

Step 3 - Now perform this formula:

```
for i in range(1,12):
dates[i] = (dates[i-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i-1]) % 12
```

Step 4 - The final result will be

```
dates = [11 10 10 8 8 6 5 4 4 2 1 12]
```

Although I was able to do this I need to factor in the years of what NDD started with so what I want to have is **THE RESULT SHOULD BE:**

```
11/18 10/18 10/18 8/18 8/18 6/18 5/18 4/18 4/18 2/18 1/18 12/17
```

Now to go with what I have. This is what I have for NDD:

```
print(type(NDD))
```

Here is a view values from NDD

```
print(NDD[0:3])
0   2018-08-01
1   2018-07-01
2   2018-11-01
```

Here are the number_of_payments information:

```
print(type(number_of_payments))
<class 'list'>
```

Here is the first row (same as the example above)

```
print(number_of_payments[0])
[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  5.  1.  0.  2.  1.]
```

This is what I am trying to do to get the result but it does not work:

```
dates = []
for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
    dates.append([NDD[i]])
    for j in range(1, len(number_of_payments[i])):
        dates[i].append((dates[i][j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i][j-1]) % 12)
for date_row in dates:
    for n, i in enumerate(date_row):
        if i == 0:
            date_row[n] = 12
print(dates[0])
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-907a0962fd65> in <module>()
      4     dates.append([NDD[i]])
      5     for j in range(1, len(number_of_payments[i])):
----> 6         dates[i].append((dates[i][j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i][j-1]) % 12)
      7 for date_row in dates:
      8     for n, i in enumerate(date_row):

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib._Timestamp.__add__ (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:22331)()

ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.
```

I hope this is clear.

**Entire Code:**

```
# In[9]:


# Import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from functools import reduce
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *


# In[10]:


# Import data file
df = pd.read_csv("Paystring Data.csv")
df.head()


# In[11]:


# Get column data into a list
x = list(df)


# In[12]:


# Append column data into cpi, NDD, and as of dates
NDD = df['NDD 8/31']
cpi = df['Contractual PI']
as_of_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df.columns.str[:8], errors='coerce'))
as_of_date = as_of_date[1:13]
payment_months =  pd.to_datetime(as_of_date, errors = 'coerce').dt.month.tolist()


# In[13]:


# Get cash flows
cf = df.iloc[:,1:13].replace('[^0-9.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
cf = cf.values


# In[14]:


# Calculate number of payments
number_of_payments = []
i = 0
while i < len(cpi):
    number_of_payments.append(np.round_(cf[:i + 1] / cpi[i]))
    i = i + 1


# In[15]:


# Calculate the new NDD dates
# dates = []
# for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
#     dates.append([NDD_month[i]])
#     for j in range(1, len(number_of_payments[i][0])):
#         dates[i].append((dates[i][j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i][0][j-1]) % 12)
# print(dates[0])
d = []
for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
    d.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(NDD[i], '%m/%d/%Y'))
def calc_payment(previous_payment,i):
    return previous_payment+relativedelta(months=(-1*i)) 
dates = [d]
for p in number_of_payments:
    dates += [calc_payment(result[-1],p)]





# In[ ]:


# Calculate paystring
paystring = []
for i in range(len(payment_months)):
    for j in range(len(dates[i])):
        if payment_months[i] < dates[i][j]:
            paystring.append(0)
        elif NDD_day[j] > 1:
            paystring.append((payment_months[i] + 12 - dates[i][j]) % 12)
        else:
            paystring.append( (payment_months[i] + 12 - dates[i][j]) + 1) % 12)
print(paystring[0])
```

I am currently stuck on implementing Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz solution to adapt to this. Here is also a screen shot of the data frame. Please let me know if more information would help.

**Update:**

I cannot seem to get any good answers since the only person that had a close solution deleted it. I have now posted this to https://www.codementor.io/u/dashboard/my-requests/5p8xirscop?from=active. Paying 100 USD for anyone to give me a complete solution and I mean totally complete not just sort of complete.

[image]

**Edit:**

I try to run this code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import reduce
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
df=pd.read_csv('Paystring Data.csv')
cpi=df['Contractual PI']
start=df['NDD 8/31'].apply(pd.to_datetime).astype(datetime)
cf = df.iloc[:,1:13].replace('[^0-9.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
payments =  cf.apply(lambda p: round(p/cpi))
diffs=payments.cumsum(axis=1).applymap(lambda i: relativedelta(months=(-1*i)))
payments=diffs.apply(lambda x: start+x)
result=pd.concat([start,payments],axis=1)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    657             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y,
--> 658                                           raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)
    659         except TypeError:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    210         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 211                          **eval_kwargs)
    212     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, truediv, reversed, **eval_kwargs)
    121     if result is None:
--> 122         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error)
    123 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, **eval_kwargs)
     63     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
---> 64         return op(a, b)
     65 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __radd__(self, other)
    390     def __radd__(self, other):
--> 391         return self.__add__(other)
    392 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __add__(self, other)
    362                 month += 12
--> 363         day = min(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1],
    364                   self.day or other.day)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in monthrange(year, month)
    123         raise IllegalMonthError(month)
--> 124     day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
    125     ndays = mdays[month] + (month == February and isleap(year))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in weekday(year, month, day)
    115        day (1-31)."""
--> 116     return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
    117 

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
    681             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
--> 682                 return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
    683         except Exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    663                 mask = notnull(x) & notnull(y)
--> 664                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], _values_from_object(y[mask]))
    665             elif isinstance(x, np.ndarray):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __radd__(self, other)
    390     def __radd__(self, other):
--> 391         return self.__add__(other)
    392 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __add__(self, other)
    362                 month += 12
--> 363         day = min(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1],
    364                   self.day or other.day)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in monthrange(year, month)
    123         raise IllegalMonthError(month)
--> 124     day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
    125     ndays = mdays[month] + (month == February and isleap(year))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in weekday(year, month, day)
    115        day (1-31)."""
--> 116     return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
    117 

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6cf75731780d> in <module>()
     10 payments =  cf.apply(lambda p: round(p/cpi))
     11 diffs=payments.cumsum(axis=1).applymap(lambda i: relativedelta(months=(-1*i)))
---> 12 payments=diffs.apply(lambda x: start+x)
     13 result=pd.concat([start,payments],axis=1)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4260                         f, axis,
   4261                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4262                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4263             else:
   4264                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4356             try:
   4357                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4358                     results[i] = func(v)
   4359                     keys.append(v.name)
   4360             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-1-6cf75731780d> in <lambda>(x)
     10 payments =  cf.apply(lambda p: round(p/cpi))
     11 diffs=payments.cumsum(axis=1).applymap(lambda i: relativedelta(months=(-1*i)))
---> 12 payments=diffs.apply(lambda x: start+x)
     13 result=pd.concat([start,payments],axis=1)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    719                 lvalues = lvalues.values
    720 
--> 721         result = wrap_results(safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues))
    722         return construct_result(
    723             left,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
    690                 if is_object_dtype(lvalues):
    691                     return libalgos.arrmap_object(lvalues,
--> 692                                                   lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
    693             raise
    694 

pandas\_libs\algos_common_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.arrmap_object()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in <lambda>(x)
    690                 if is_object_dtype(lvalues):
    691                     return libalgos.arrmap_object(lvalues,
--> 692                                                   lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
    693             raise
    694 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __radd__(self, other)
    389 
    390     def __radd__(self, other):
--> 391         return self.__add__(other)
    392 
    393     def __rsub__(self, other):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py in __add__(self, other)
    361                 year -= 1
    362                 month += 12
--> 363         day = min(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1],
    364                   self.day or other.day)
    365         repl = {"year": year, "month": month, "day": day}

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in monthrange(year, month)
    122     if not 1 <= month <= 12:
    123         raise IllegalMonthError(month)
--> 124     day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
    125     ndays = mdays[month] + (month == February and isleap(year))
    126     return day1, ndays

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in weekday(year, month, day)
    114     """Return weekday (0-6 ~ Mon-Sun) for year (1970-...), month (1-12),
    115        day (1-31)."""
--> 116     return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
    117 
    118 

TypeError: ('integer argument expected, got float', 'occurred at index Aug 2018(P&I Applied)')
```

Comment: The first part of this description makes sense to me now (also, please edit your old questions instead of asking new ones for the same thing---when you edit, they get put back up at the top of the queue---or at least delete the old ones).

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to append lists themselves. Your first example says dates should just be a list. But then you're doing `dates[i].append(stuff)`. This means `dates` is a list of lists. Which way is correct?

Comment: dates is going to be a list of lists

Comment: I just did lists in the first example to illustrate clearly

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds If needed I could zip and send the whole jupyter notebook file (just a .csv and 1 notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Python 3 (you need to pip install `python-dateutil`).
(edited per comments)

```
df=pd.read_csv('Paystring Data.csv')
cpi=df['Contractual PI']
start=df['NDD 8/31'].apply(pd.to_datetime).astype(datetime)
cf = df.iloc[:,1:13].replace('[^0-9.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
payments =  cf.apply(lambda p: round(p/cpi))
diffs=payments.cumsum(axis=1).applymap(lambda i: relativedelta(months=(-1*i)))
payments=diffs.apply(lambda x: start+x)
result=pd.concat([start,payments],axis=1)
```

Comment: I think this answer is partly good (using `dateutil.relativedelta` to handle the month offsets, especially), but the `reduce` code is impossible for me to understand. That may just mean I'm a mediocre functional programmer, but I'm pretty sure you could write an explicit loop to do the same calculation and it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: It is just taking the payments one by one and the list of dates so far it then adds the calculated payment to the lisg

Comment: I am trying to utilize your code but its not really working for me at all. Should I provide my entire code so that you can modify what I have?

Comment: Also what is result[-1] in the last part of your code?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3beef40f97a2> in <module>()
     13 dates = [d]
     14 for p in number_of_payments:
---> 15     dates += [calc_payment(result[-1],p)]
     16 print(dates[0])
     17 

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Following your steps this is where I am:                                                               'd = []
for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
    d.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(NDD[i], '%m/%d/%Y'))
def calc_payment(previous_payment,i):
    return previous_payment+relativedelta(months=(-1*i)) 
dates = [d]
for p in number_of_payments:
    dates += [calc_payment(result[-1],p)]'

Comment: What's NDD in your code? As for the result[-1] that means the last item in result

Comment: I take NDD from the data frame column which is a column vector of dates of type str. I am trying to get your code to work for mine but I cannot get it to work as result is not defined

Comment: You have the best answer thus far but I just need some help getting what you did to work for my code.

Comment: And do you have a single number of payments vector or is that a data frame?

Comment: No the number_of_payments is a 1345 by 12 matrix or list of lists.

Comment: As in the number_of_payments has a 1345 rows and 12 columns

Comment: Should I somehow post the .csv file? My apologies for the plethora of messages...

Comment: For your edited post I am getting an error for ndd['start'], TypeError: ('data type not understood', 'occurred at index ndd')

Comment: you need to from datetime import datetime (and not import datetime)

Comment: I apologize but your code is still not working for me at all, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please see edited where I attempt to incorporate your code. I really think we could both save us time if I can send you my .csv file

Answer (score 1):

#### [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

Since you are using Pandas, I recommend you take advantage of the *vectorised* methods available to Pandas / NumPy. In this case, it seems like you wish to subtract the *cumulative sum* of a list from a fixed starting point.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NDD = '11/1/2018'
date = pd.to_datetime(NDD)
number_of_payments = [1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1]

res = date.month - np.cumsum([0] + number_of_payments[:-1])
res[res <= 0] += 12

print(res)

array([11, 10, 10,  8,  8,  6,  5,  4,  4,  2,  1, 12], dtype=int32)
```

You haven't provided an input dataframe, so it's difficult to determine exactly what help you need to implement the above logic, but it is easily extendable to larger data sets.

Comment: I could give you the dataframe if that would help? Not sure how to attach a .csv file

Comment: Also I am not sure where the years are in the result

Comment: I can provide the .csv file or send it to you?

Comment: Yea, your result does not make sense it should be 11/18 10/18 10/18 8/18 8/18 6/18 5/18 4/18 4/18 2/18 1/18 12/17

Comment: Note you can treat each number of payments to be of year 2018

Answer (score 1):

**Python3 (datetime & list)**
Comments are in-lined.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def calc_payments(ndd: str, num_of_payments: list):
    def subtract_months(month: datetime, num: int):
        # Make sure given month is at 1 day of month
        month = month.replace(day=1)
        for _ in range(num):
            # Subtract the date by 1 day to calc prev month last day
            # Change the calculated prev month last day to 1st day
            month = (month - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
        return month

    ndd_date: datetime = datetime.strptime(ndd, '%m/%d/%Y')
    payments = list()

    payments.append(ndd_date)

    # Loop/logic as described in Step 3 by OP
    for i in range(1, len(num_of_payments)):
        ndd_date = subtract_months(ndd_date, num_of_payments[i - 1])
        payments.append(ndd_date)

    return payments


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NDD = "11/1/2018"
    number_of_payments = [1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1]
    for f in calc_payments(NDD, number_of_payments):
        # Format date to month/2-digit-year
        print(f"{f.month}/{f.strftime('%y')}", end=" ")
```

Comment: I am really confused by your code, should I just zip the jupyter file to you so that I can follow your answer

Comment: The section __main__ is just for illustration in this post and your can remove it completely.  You may define the function "calc_payments" in one of your  existing python module or define a new one. It's upto you...

Comment: How do I apply your code to what I have? I just cannot adapt it to what I have.

Comment: Hi, interested in finishing this entire code for 100 USD?